# Can gdb debug suid root programs?

Tags: shell, gdb, setuid, suid

I did a program that call setuid(0) and execve("/bin/bash",NULL,NULL).

Then I did `chown root:root a.out && chmod +s a.out`

When I execute `./a.out` I get a root shell. However when I do `gdb a.out` it starts the process as normal user, and launch a user shell.

So... can I debug a suided root program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only by running `gdb` as root. (In other words, no.)

For security reasons, normal users are not allowed to trace processes belonging to other users, especially root.

Comment: Only root can call `ptrace()` (system call used to debug applications)